# Infopath forms - Filter external datasource items by user profile

Tags: list, infopath, user-profile, custom-form

As a continuation of [another question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22564/sharepoint-2010-related-fields-in-dropdowns-how-to) of mine, I'm implementing cascading drop-downs using InfoPath based on [this article](http://koobarspoint.blogspot.com/2010/06/cascading-drop-downs-with-infopath-2010.html) . The thing works nice but I'm wondering if there is a way to also filter the list items by the user profile (current profile of the user creating an item based on the cascades).

I want to display the values in the combos based on the user profile (i.e. I want to add a "profile" to each entry in the "Suburbs" list and if the user has that profile it sees the option else it does not).

Is it possible to filter the external datasource items by user profile?